# What are the memory readouts referring to?

Tags: memory-management

There are two sets of memory readouts I'm puzzled by. I need a better explanation of what they mean.

One is in the Info Window and says something like Mem:119.14M(9.99M)
One is with the render output and says Mem:98.17M (9.99M, Peak 201.62M)

With rendering, I thought that the first number was the Memory currently used and that the Peak was the max memory every used in the render. I have no idea what the 9.99 figure was about. Am I correct?

And what does the Memory amount in the Info window refer to?

Thanks.